# Code required on enter in timeMeasureEnd block if an agent has to pass without passing through it's corresponding timeMeasureStart Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I would like to time different segments of my model where some agents go, but not all. However, all agents no matter if they went through the timeMeasureStart or not, will have to pass by its corresponding timeMeasureEnd. How to proceed without getting the error of `The agent has not been through a corresponding TimeMeasureStart object` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `timeMeasureStart` and `timeMeasureEnd` blocks, you can just add variables inside your agent called `startTime`, `endTime` and `cycleTime` of type double.

Then, at the end of the process flow, you can type `agent.cycleTime=agent.endTime-agent.startTime;`. You will have the time in system for each agent. And you have the freedom to choose which agents' information to keep and which ones to discard.

Comment: End of the process flow meaning where exactly?

Comment: Where you currently have timeMeasureEnd.

Comment: In the ```on enter``` parameter in the block which I would like the time collection to end?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: I am given 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Patient.endTime' and the same with the rest of the variables. I am using Patient here as it is the agent type being processed through the model.

Comment: Please add the screenshot of how you define and use the variables. Something is not correct...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241857/discussion-between-nicka-and-yashar-ahmadov).

Comment: To clarify, ```agent.cycleTime=agent.endTime-agent.startTime;``` into the block in which I want the timing to end, then inserting ```myDataSet.add(agent.cycleTime)``` into the dataset that has been defined inside the agent Patient?

Comment: @NickA yes.. correct

Comment: 'agent cannot be resolved to a variable' is thrown at me in the myDataSet data set